# is there a better way to delare a struct array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

i have to put data from 12 nodes in a struct
i do it now like this

```
int j = 0;
edges[j].node1_location = 1;
edges[j].node2_location = 2;
edges[j].isLandWay = true;
edges[j].needToBeChecked = true;
edges[j].weight = 6;

j++;
edges[j].node1_location = 1;
edges[j].node2_location = 3;
edges[j].isLandWay = false;
edges[j].needToBeChecked = true;
edges[j].weight = 1;
```

but i don't like this
is there a better way to do this (the data is unique for every node)
i was thinking about making an external file where i put the data in and load that in.
advantige of that the code will be cleaner
disadvantige the data never changes

edit 
thanks all for the reactions
i think that i go for an xml or csv file

Comment: any chance for plain old CSV file?

Comment: Could use a method to create the edges to reduce the lines of code `Edge CreateEdge(int node1_location, int node2_location, ...)` then just `edges[j] = CreateEdge(...)`

Answer (score 2):

May not be *much* cleaner but you could code the values as an array:

```
object[][] data = new object[][]
{
    {1, 2, true,  true, 6 },
    {1, 3, false, true, 1 },
...
}
```

then just use a loop to initialize your objects:

```
for(int j = 0; j < data.GetLength(0); j++)
{
    edges[j].node1_location  = (int) data[j,0];
    edges[j].node2_location  = (int) data[j,1];
    edges[j].isLandWay       = (bool)data[j,2];
    edges[j].needToBeChecked = (bool)data[j,3];
    edges[j].weight          = (int) data[j,4];
}
```

Another option would be to create your array in a temporary project to serialize it to XML. Then your *real* program can just de-serialize the XML.

Comment: nice one with two-dimensional array, clears code a bit, but would be great to extract that code into separate file and keep it together.

Answer (score 1):

Some short hand code could be:

```
Edge[] edges = new[]
    {
        new Edge() 
        {
            node1_location = 1,
            node2_location = 2,
            isLandWay = true,
            needToBeChecked = true,
            weight = 6
        },
        new Edge() 
        {
            node1_location = 1,
            node2_location = 3,
            isLandWay = false,
            needToBeChecked = true,
            weight = 1
        },
        // Add more nodes here.    
    };
```

Comment: You can even shorten more by dropping the parentheses :)

Answer (score 0):

If you were to define a constructor for the struct, you could then say:

```
int j = 0;
edges[j++] = new Edge(1, 2, true,  true, 6);
edges[j++] = new Edge(1, 3, false, true, 1);
etc.
```

or

```
Edge edges[] = new edges[] {
  new Edge(1, 2, true,  true, 6),
  new Edge(1, 3, false, true, 1),
  etc.
};
```

Note that using a constructor does not imply any requirement that one encapsulate the struct fields in properties.  If the purpose of a structure is to behave as a bunch of variables stuck together with duct tape, making the structure's fields public is a good way to make that purpose clear.  If the specified behavior of a struct allows one to read all the fields and create instances with any desired combination of field values, those requirements imply semantics equivalent to an exposed-field structure, so one may as well simply *use* an exposed-field structure.  Note that the evils of so-called "mutable structures" relate to problems with struct methods or properties that mutate `this`, rather than to those which allow outside code to mutate their public fields.  Given:

```
struct Foo { public int a,b; }
Foo myFoo = computeSomething();
```

then the meaning of `myFoo.a` is nothing more nor less than "the last value written to myFoo.a", or in this case, "the value which `computeSomething` stored in field `a` of the returned value.  The `computeSomething()` method may make some promises about what's in that field, but `Foo` does not.